# How to Insert PHP variables from php review section into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'd like to create a simple review section using PHP.
It can echo just fine, however the data doesn't get filled into the database.
What can I do to fix this?
I'm quite new to all of this.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["reviewsub"])){
    $rating= ($_POST["rating"]);
    $review=($_POST["review"]);
    echo "".$review."";
    echo "" .$rating."";
    echo "geluuuuukt";

 
try {

$db = new PDO("dbinfo");
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews(review_id, review, rating,)VALUES('COUNT($rating)','$review', '$rating')");
if($query->execute()) {
   echo "Success. Your review has been uploaded";
}
 else {
   echo "An error has occured";
 }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

review_id is the primary key of the table. I'd like it to be based off the amount of reviews made. So if you're first to review, the id would be 1
This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Review This Product</legend>    
    <p><label for="rating">Rating</label><input type="radio" name="rating"
      value="5" /> 5 
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /> 4
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" /> 3 
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" /> 2 
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" /> 1
      </p>
    <p>
        <label for="review">Review</label><input type="text" name="review">
       </textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="reviewsub" value="Submit Review">
    </p>

</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select count of rating:

```
$nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from reviews')->fetchColumn();
```

Then use it:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review, rating) VALUES ($nRows, $review, $rating)");
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Could it be that there's something wrong with my database?

Comment: This is my database, it shows no errors.

NAME           TYPE                    COLLATION
review_id | Primary int(10) | 
username| varchar(50) | utf8_unicode_ci 
rating |   tinyint(1)         |    
review |   mediumtext    |    utf8_unicode_ci 
review_date | timestamp  | current_timestamp()